# Is it possible to check that specific data matches the query without loading it to the index?

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search, offline

Imagine that I have a specific data string and a specific query. The simple way to check that the query matches the data is to load the data into the Elastic index and run the online query. But can I do it without putting it into the index?

Maybe there are some open-source libraries that implement the Elastic search functionality offline, so I can call something like getScore(data, query)? Or it's possible to implement by using specific API endpoints?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to leverage the [percolator type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/percolator.html).

What this allows you to do is to store the query instead of the document and then test whether a document would match the stored query.

For instance, you first create an index with a field of type `percolator` that will contain your query (you also need to add in the mapping any field used by the query so ES knows what their types are):

```
PUT my_index
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "query": {
                "type": "percolator"
            },
            "message": {
                "type": "text"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can index a real query, like this:

```
PUT my_index/_doc/match_value
{
    "query" : {
        "match" : {
            "message" : "bonsai tree"
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, you can check using the [`percolate` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-percolate-query.html) if the query you've just stored would match

```
GET /my_index/_search
{
    "query" : {
        "percolate" : {
            "field" : "query",
            "document" : {
                "message" : "A new bonsai tree in the office"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So all you need to do is to only store the query (not the documents), and then you can use the `percolate` query to check if the documents would have been selected by the query you stored, without having to store the documents themselves.